# how to implement "Microsoft Outlook Express" (msimn.exe) under Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, email, migration, outlook-express

Outlook 2013 has random show stopper issues.

With Windows 95, Microsoft introduced `msimn.exe` as "Microsoft internet Mail and News", later, to confuse the public, Microsoft renamed the program "Microsoft Outlook **Express**", a.k.a. **OE**.

With Vista, Microsoft stopped shipping OE.

i still run OE on a winXP box even though winXP is no longer supported.

i'd like to migrate OE from my winXP box to my win8.1 ... however, i'm wondering whether anyone has successfully done such a migration and, if so, what, if any, are the *pitfalls*?

*please note other alternatives like Thunderbird et al are not to my personal liking (they're far too bloated imho).*

Comment: Have you tried windows Live Mail - is it to your liking?

Comment: Some options at http://superuser.com/questions/552697/where-can-i-get-outlook-express-for-windows-8 and http://superuser.com/questions/391355/outlook-express-in-win7

Comment: Live mail is what I use, works fine and is similar to OE6, I just had to change some of the view settings to my needs. It allows importing of messages from OE6

Comment: Live Mail is not for me; it's just not like OE; also, i prefer the way OE uses the .dbx file type to store e-mails, as well as many other OE features; OE is very well designed for end users who like to keep their hands on the keyboard; OE also lets my choose to colour received e-mails according to rules that one can specify.  Regardless, thank you for the suggestions, however, i'm really hoping that it will be possible to migrate OE to my win 8.1 environment.

Comment: @Mokubai thnx for the links but both links require i virtualize XP ... i don't want all of XP, just OE.